# H265 seq parameter set data Syntax table required

Tags: parsing, video-streaming, video-processing, hevc

I have been searching for seq parameter set syntax table for H265 for long time ,but cant able to find. I have H264 syntax table which i used for parsing h264 file and it works fine .I am trying to do the same with H265 video file to get the resolution. i have parser which i derived my version from-> for reference https://github.com/virinext/hevcesbrowser

Note:With Hevcbrowser source i can able to see and understand the value and type but i not getting the same So syntax table will be helpful

Need to know the type like Ue U or Se for H265 and its value
. Please refer to this image for details
[Table of H264 Sps parameter syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIgT6.png)

```
int32_t CtbLog2SizeY = m_spsMap[spsId] -> log2_min_luma_coding_block_size_minus3 + 3 + m_spsMap[spsId] -> log2_diff_max_min_luma_coding_block_size;
uint32_t CtbSizeY = 1 << CtbLog2SizeY;
uint32_t PicWidthInCtbsY = m_spsMap[spsId] -> pic_width_in_luma_samples / CtbSizeY;
```

i am expecting 640 at PicWidthInCtbsY

```
    int h265_parser_sps(unsigned char * buffer, unsigned int bufferlen, int *width,int * height)
{
    unsigned int StartBit=0;
    de_emulation_prevention(buffer,&bufferlen);

    uint32_t    sps_video_parameter_set_id = 0;
    uint32_t    sps_max_sub_layers_minus1 = 0;
    bool        sps_temporal_id_nesting_flag;
    uint32_t    sps_seq_parameter_set_id = 0;
    uint32_t    chroma_format_idc;
    bool        separate_colour_plane_flag = false;
    uint32_t    pic_width_in_luma_samples=0;
    uint32_t    pic_height_in_luma_samples=0;
    bool        conformance_window_flag;
    uint32_t    conf_win_left_offset;
    uint32_t    conf_win_right_offset;
    uint32_t    conf_win_top_offset;
    uint32_t    conf_win_bottom_offset;
    uint32_t    bit_depth_luma_minus8;
    uint32_t    bit_depth_chroma_minus8;
    uint32_t    log2_max_pic_order_cnt_lsb_minus4;
    bool        sps_sub_layer_ordering_info_present_flag;
    bool        rbsp_stop_one_bit;

    u(16,buffer,StartBit);//nal_unit_header
    sps_video_parameter_set_id      = u(4,buffer,StartBit);
    sps_max_sub_layers_minus1       = u(3,buffer,StartBit);
    sps_temporal_id_nesting_flag    = u(1,buffer,StartBit);
    cout<<"sps_video_parameter_set_id:"<<sps_video_parameter_set_id<<endl;
    cout<<"sps_max_sub_layers_minus1:"<<sps_max_sub_layers_minus1<<endl;
    cout<<"sps_temporal_id_nesting_flag:"<<sps_temporal_id_nesting_flag<<endl;

    h265_parse_ptl(sps_max_sub_layers_minus1,buffer,StartBit,bufferlen);

    sps_seq_parameter_set_id    = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
    cout<<"sps_seq_parameter_set_id:"<<sps_seq_parameter_set_id<<endl;

    //p_sps = &sps[sps_seq_parameter_set_id];

    chroma_format_idc           = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
    cout<<"chroma_format_idc:"<<chroma_format_idc<<endl;

    if (3 == chroma_format_idc)
    {
        separate_colour_plane_flag = u(1,buffer,StartBit);
    }
    else
        separate_colour_plane_flag = 0;
    cout<<"separate_colour_plane_flag:"<<separate_colour_plane_flag<<endl;

    pic_width_in_luma_samples   = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
    pic_height_in_luma_samples  = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
    cout<<"pic_width_in_luma_samples:"<<pic_width_in_luma_samples<<endl;
    cout<<"pic_height_in_luma_samples:"<<pic_height_in_luma_samples<<endl;
    *width=pic_width_in_luma_samples;
    *height=pic_height_in_luma_samples;


    conformance_window_flag = u(1,buffer,StartBit);
    cout<<"conformance_window_flag:"<<conformance_window_flag<<endl;

    if (conformance_window_flag)
    {
        conf_win_left_offset    = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
        conf_win_right_offset   = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
        conf_win_top_offset     = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
        conf_win_bottom_offset  = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
    }

    bit_depth_luma_minus8               = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
    bit_depth_chroma_minus8             = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
    log2_max_pic_order_cnt_lsb_minus4   = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
    cout<<"bit_depth_luma_minus8:"<<bit_depth_luma_minus8<<endl;
    cout<<"bit_depth_chroma_minus8:"<<bit_depth_chroma_minus8<<endl;
    cout<<"log2_max_pic_order_cnt_lsb_minus4:"<<log2_max_pic_order_cnt_lsb_minus4<<endl;

    sps_sub_layer_ordering_info_present_flag = u(1,buffer,StartBit);
    cout<<"sps_sub_layer_ordering_info_present_flag:"<<sps_sub_layer_ordering_info_present_flag<<endl;

    int i;
    uint32_t *sps_max_dec_pic_buffering_minus1   = new uint32_t[sps_max_sub_layers_minus1 + 1];
    uint32_t *sps_max_num_reorder_pics           = new uint32_t[sps_max_sub_layers_minus1 + 1];
    uint32_t *sps_max_latency_increase_plus1     = new uint32_t[sps_max_sub_layers_minus1 + 1];

    for (i = (sps_sub_layer_ordering_info_present_flag ? 0 : sps_max_sub_layers_minus1); i <= sps_max_sub_layers_minus1; i++ )
    {
        sps_max_dec_pic_buffering_minus1[i] = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
        sps_max_num_reorder_pics[i]         = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
        sps_max_latency_increase_plus1[i]   = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
    }

    uint32_t log2_min_luma_coding_block_size_minus3;
    uint32_t log2_diff_max_min_luma_coding_block_size;
    uint32_t log2_min_transform_block_size_minus2;
    uint32_t log2_diff_max_min_transform_block_size;
    uint32_t max_transform_hierarchy_depth_inter;
    uint32_t max_transform_hierarchy_depth_intra;
    bool     scaling_list_enabled_flag;

    log2_min_luma_coding_block_size_minus3      = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
    log2_diff_max_min_luma_coding_block_size    = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
    log2_min_transform_block_size_minus2        = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
    log2_diff_max_min_transform_block_size      = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
    max_transform_hierarchy_depth_inter         = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
    max_transform_hierarchy_depth_intra         = Ue(buffer,bufferlen,StartBit);
    scaling_list_enabled_flag                   = u(1,buffer,StartBit);
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]. What exactly is your problem? What error are you encountering?

Comment: I still don't understand your question, are you looking for details of the HEVC coding? If so thats not really a programming question, you need to purchase a copy of the HEVC/h.265 standard

Comment: Just need to calculate pic_width_in_luma_samples and pic_height_in_luma_samples for 640 *360 or any other resolution.i get 44 for pic_width_in_luma_samples  and 6 for pic_height_in_luma_samples with my code

Comment: and what is your code? please provide a [mre]

Comment: i have mention the link above i am using Hevcbroswser samples as it is. check the parser.cpp files

Comment: a [mre] needs to be within the question without relying on external links. Why do you expect `PicWidthInCtbsY` to be 640?

Comment: i dont no were to fetch that so iam using PicWidthInCtbsY .if it is wrong .i just need to know how to fetch the height and width with some samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need the specifications document of H.265/HEVC, which you can find [here](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-H.265-201911-I!!PDF-E&type=items). It's quite a long document obviously. You should look for the right table.

Comment: plz see the Edit